# AngularJS testing with Protractor- tests that used to pass now failing due to Waits timing out

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor, automated-tests

About 6 months or so ago I started developing an automated test suite for an AngularJS application developed by my company, using [Protractor](http://www.protractortest.org).

After I had been working on this for a couple of months, some other work came up which I had to prioritise over the test suite, and so I haven't looked at it since around the end of November/ December last year.

When I stopped working on it, I made sure that everything that I had done up to that date was in a fully working state (commented/ removed the tests I had started working on but hadn't finished, etc), and committed that git branch. At this point, I was able to run all of the tests I had written up until then using the command `protractor conf.js`, and I could see that they were all passing as expected.

I recently checked my `testing` branch out again, as I have a day or two in between other projects, and thought I could make use of the time by working on the testing again.

The first thing I did once I had checked out the `testing` branch, was to try running my test scripts again, to ensure everything I had implemented so far was still working.

However, while most of the tests do still pass, a few of them are now failing due to time outs, even though I had made sure that all of the timing elements were working correctly before I shelved the testing for a while.

I have tried increasing the times that my tests should `sleep` or `wait` for things at the points at which they are failing, but this doesn't seem to have made a difference.

The particular tests that are now failing due to time outs are:

1.

```
it('should navigate to the Config/Platform page & check the values are all correct', function() {
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    browser.actions().mouseMove(configMenuBtn).perform();
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(pageConfigPlatformBtn), 8000).then(browser.sleep(5000).then( /*ERF(14/11/2017 @ 1630) browser.sleep() required to give DialogMgr service time to complete */
        pageConfigPlatformBtn.click().then(function(){

            browser.sleep(10000); /*ERF(14/11/2017 @ 1640) This line is needed- because of how the form HTML is created, it needs time to be replaced by configured HTML that is displaying the required fields */

            var eth0Mode = element(by.model('modelinstances.platform.eth_0_mode'));
            var eth0Address = element(by.model('modelinstances.platform.static_ip.eth_0_address'));
            var eth0Netmask = element(by.model('modelinstances.platform.static_ip.eth_0_netmask'));
            var eth0gateway = element(by.model('modelinstances.platform.static_ip.eth_0_gateway'));
            var eth1mode = element(by.model('modelinstances.platform.eth_1_mode'));
            var eth1Address = element(by.model('modelinstances.platform.static_ip.eth_1_address'));
            var eth1netmask = element(by.model('modelinstances.platform.static_ip.eth_1_netmask'));
            var eth1gateway = element(by.model('modelinstances.platform.static_ip.eth_1_gateway'));

            expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch(moxaConfigPlatformUrlRegExpPattern);
            expect(eth0Mode.getAttribute('value')).toBe("Static IP");
            expect(eth0Address.getAttribute('value')).toBe("192.168.1.127");
            expect(eth0Netmask.getAttribute('value')).toBe("255.255.255.0");
            expect(eth0gateway.getAttribute('value')).toBe("192.168.1.1");
            expect(eth1mode.getAttribute('value')).toBe("Static IP");
            expect(eth1Address.getAttribute('value')).toBe("192.168.2.127");
            expect(eth1netmask.getAttribute('value')).toBe("255.255.255.0");
            expect(eth1gateway.getAttribute('value')).toBe("");
    })));
})
```

The failure message for this test is:

> App should navigate to the Config/Platform page & check the values are all correct
>     Message:
>       Failed: Wait timed out after 8002ms
>     Stack:
>       TimeoutError: Wait timed out after 8002ms

2.

```
it('should navigate to the Config/Date/Time page', function() {
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    browser.actions().mouseMove(configMenuBtn).perform();
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(pageConfigDateTimeBtn), 2000).then(browser.sleep(1000).then( /*ERF(14/11/2017 @ 1630) browser.sleep() required to give DialogMgr service time to complete */
    pageConfigDateTimeBtn.click().then(function() {
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toBe(VM + '/#/config/systemtime');
    })));
})
```

The failure message for this test is:

> App should navigate to the Config/Date/Time page
>     Message:
>       Failed: Wait timed out after 2023ms
>     Stack:
>       TimeoutError: Wait timed out after 2023ms

3.

```
it('should navigate to the Tag Browser page (final test)', function() {
    console.log("Start final Tag Browser page test");
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(pagesMenuBtn), 10000).then(
        browser.actions().mouseMove(pagesMenuBtn).perform().then(
            browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(pageConfigDateTimeBtn), 2000).then(browser.sleep(1000)).then( /*ERF(14/11/2017 @ 1650) browser.sleep() required to give DialogMgr service time to complete */

                browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(pageTagBrowserBtn), 12000).then(
                    pageTagBrowserBtn.click().then(
                        function() {
                            console.log("Tag Browser menu button clicked");
                        }).then(
                            browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(tagBrowserPageTagsLink), 20000).then(
                                function(){
                                    console.log("End Tag Browser page test (then call)");
                                    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toBe(VM + '/#/pages/tagbrowser');
                                }
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
    );
});
```

The failure message for this test is:

> App should navigate to the Tag Browser page (final test)
>     Message:
>       Failed: Wait timed out after 2009ms
>     Stack:
>       TimeoutError: Wait timed out after 2009ms

I have tried increasing the times that the `wait()` calls are being passed, but this hasn't resolved the issue.

I have read in the past that automated testing can be quite flakey, and that changes to the environment in which they're run can cause them to fail- so I'm guessing it's possible that because my computer will have changed since the tests were last run successfully (i.e. new software installed), this may be causing the tests to fail...?

Is there a method of 'best practice' for resolving this sort of issue with automated testing, or is just a case of having to go back and tweak my test scripts until they start passing again?

It's probably worth mentioning that all of my test are written in a `spec.js` file, and that these tests which failed are the last 3 of 18 test scripts in that file (i.e. the first 15 all still pass).

Anyone have any ideas how I can resolve this/ get my tests passing again?

Comment: Dry and solid come to mind for best practice. Are your tests running in a particular order

Comment: Why have you set `waitForAngularEnabled` to false? Are you testing a non angular page?

Comment: Your spec files haven't changed, but has the web page they are running against changed?